# Force integration to be linear over sum?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, attributes

Is there an obvious way to force Mathematica to separately integrate the terms in a sum? According to the docs,

> When part of a sum cannot be integrated explicitly, the whole sum will stay unintegrated.

But I want to do this because some of the terms have a nice closed form, and some don't, but I want to compute the former.

Here's what I've done; it works, but it seems inelegant:

```
integrand = m^2 + mp^2 + mp f[mp] (* the actual integrand is much more complicated! *)

(myint[integrand // Expand] 
    //.  myint[a_ + b_] :> myint[a] + myint[b]
    //.  myint[i_] :> Integrate[i, {mp, -1, 1}]) // FullSimplify
```

Which gives the correct

```
2/3 +  2*m^2 + Integrate[mp*f[mp], {mp, -1, 1}]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could also use `Distribute`:

```
Integrate[integrand, mp] // Distribute
```

> $m^2 \text{mp}+\frac{\text{mp}^3}{3}+\int \text{mp} f[\text{mp}] \, d\text{mp}$

Comment: Aha! That seems like the *real* right answer...

Comment: Nice application of `Distribute` - +1.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe That depends on the situation. The version of the Jens's answer will not attempt to compute the full integral, breaking it to pieces first. This one will first attempt to compute the full integral, and `Distribute` will work on the result. You probably do want this behavior in most cases, but I can also imagine cases where you don't want the full integration to be attempted. You could of course use this one with `Unevaluated` in those cases too.

Comment: *But beware:* neither `Map` nor `Distribute` absolve you from using common sense. For example, just like `Map` can be misused on non-sums, you can equally misuse `Distribute` with non-distributable operations! For example, don't try this at home: `Power[integrand, 2] // Distribute`

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Map` because it works with expressions of `Head` other than `List`, too:

```
integrand = m^2 + mp^2 + mp f[mp];
Map[Integrate[#, mp] &, integrand]
```

> $\int \text{mp} f(\text{mp}) \, d\text{mp}+m^2
>    \text{mp}+\frac{\text{mp}^3}{3}$

Or the definitie integral:

```
Map[Integrate[#, {mp, -1, 1}] &, integrand]
```

> $\int_{-1}^1 \text{mp} f(\text{mp}) \, d\text{mp}+2
>    m^2+\frac{2}{3}$

**Edit**

It's true that `Distribute` is more appropriate for distributing over sums (so I upvoted that too), but one potential advantage of `Map` is that it lets you do neat things like this:

```
integrand = m^2 + mp^2 == mp f[mp];    
Map[Integrate[#, {mp, -1, 1}] &, integrand]
```

> $2 m^2+\frac{2}{3}=\int_{-1}^1 \text{mp} f(\text{mp})
>    \, d\text{mp}$

In other words, I've integrated an equation on both sides. This could also be combined with distribute - so I think both have their uses.

Comment: Of course (I've been using mathematica for long enough I should have figured this out)!

Comment: Accepted, although in retrospect I guess this is dangerous if the head of the integrand isn't `Sum`...

Comment: @AndrewJaffe You can use a version like `Replace[integrand, Plus[terms__]:>Plus@@Map[Integrate[#, mp] &,{terms}]`. Since `Replace` only works on the level 0 by default, this should work fine. Yet another option is to create a custom function where you use pattern-matching to test the argument, like `integrate[integrand_Plus]:=Map[...]`. This will also effectively protect from inappropriate inputs.

Comment: Regarding the dangers, see my comment below the answer by @Simon Woods.