# Double integral yields zero unexpectedly

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

In developing a large set of functions and definitions, I sometimes got zero unexpectedly. In trying to identify the problem via Trace, the fact that Integrate doesn't give much insight in its inner workings turned out unhelpful.

Eventually I realized that the issue can be formulated as a minimal working example as follows (neither `x` nor `f[x]` are defined in the below; so this is purely symbolic):

```
Integrate[f[x] x^2, x] - Integrate[f[x], x] x^2
Integrate[Integrate[f[x] x^2, x] - Integrate[f[x], x] x^2, x]
Integrate[Integrate[f[x] x^2, x], x] - Integrate[Integrate[f[x], x] x^2, x]

(*
Out[1]= Integrate[f[x] x^2, x] - Integrate[f[x], x] x^2
Out[2]= 0
Out[3]= Integrate[Integrate[f[x] x^2, x], x] - Integrate[Integrate[f[x], x] x^2, x]
*)
```

So, the first line is not zero of itself. Using it as integrand in another integration over `x`, however, does yield zero. In fact, it does so when replacing `x^2` with `x^n` for all `n>1`.

From Integration by Parts by hand, however, I reckon that the correct answer is

```
-n Integrate[Integrate[f[x],x] x^(n-1), x]
```

integrated once more over x, which is non-zero in general.
Moreover, given the linearity of Integration, I was surprised that the second and third input line do not give rise to the same result, according to Mathematica.

I suspect that source of confusion may be the multiple use of `x`. Indeed, for specified functions, or when the Integrals are given appropriate limits, the issue disappears. As I am interested in the Indefinite integrals, this does not solve my problem. Am I missing something, mathematically? Or is this explainable behaviour of Mathematica? And, is there a workaround, that would always give me the result Out[3]?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: think about the consequences of how you choose to handle integration constants that arise from those nested indefinite integrals

Comment: @george2079 Thanks. And sure, these constants matter. I omitted them in the manual answer I gave, as I do not see how they could necessarily lead to the 0 Mathematica gives. But, to which of my questions did you specifically react? Could you please elaborate a bit more?
(And Louis: Thanks!)

Comment: Note that *Mathematica* does not seem to automatically apply linearity properties to `Integrate[]` expressions (possibly because integrability is not automatically assumed).  Related: [(16098)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16098), [(64422)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64422).

Comment: you can see by trival use of a specific `f` that your hand result of a constant `-n` is incorrect.  (I was assuming you had that right when I made my earlier comment)

Comment: @george2079 Off-topic, but I think
`Integrate[-n Integrate[Integrate[f[x],x] x^(n-1), x],x]`
 _is_ correct, apart from constants, that is, and for nice f. Confusion may have arisen from SE's line-breaking?

Comment: oh bugger, that's what I get reading the site on a little tablet.. I edited to fix the line break thing.

Comment: If you could use delayed function defintion, you would not have that problems.    g1[x_] := Integrate[f[x] x^2, x];     
g2[x_] := Integrate[f[x], x] x^2;     
g3[x_] := Integrate[g1[x] - g2[x], x];     
g4[x_] := Integrate[g1[x], x];     
g5[x_] := Integrate[g2[x], x];     
g6[x_] := Integrate[g4[x] - g5[x], x];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From more of a *programming* point of view, there is an ambiguity in

```
Integrate[Integrate[f[x] x^2, x] - Integrate[f[x], x] x^2, x]
```

The problem is of scoping.  There are in essence, three variables `x`, each belonging to one integral.  In the simpler expression

```
Integrate[f[x] x^2, x] - Integrate[f[x], x] x^2
```

it is clear that the `x` in each integral is distinct and bound inside the integral and that the `x^2` outside the second integral is free.  But wrap this in another integral that binds `x` and the question becomes which `x`'s belong to the third integral.

In some sense the answer is all of them, because the results of the interior integrals are depend on `x` which is to be integrated by the outer integral.  When properly interpreted, the interior integrals are to be evaluated first and then integrated by the outer integral.  But in this case, the inner `Integrate[]` codes return unevaluated. It *may be* (and it seems likely to me) that then all the instances of `x` in the integrand are treated as belonging to the outer integral.  It's possible that `x^2 Integrate[f[x], x]` and `Integrate[x^2 f[x], x]` are mistakenly treated as equivalent.  I'm not sure how to verify this without wading through a lot of internal trace output, which might be inconclusive.  In some sense, it's a bug, but it might be a difficult one to fix.

One workaround it to use different symbols for different contexts, but that has drawbacks, too:

```
Integrate[
 Integrate[f[x] x^2, {x, 0, y}] - Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, y}] y^2,
 {y, 0, z}]

Integrate[Integrate[f[x] x^2, {x, 0, y}], {y, 0, z}] - 
 Integrate[Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, y}] y^2, {y, 0, z}]
```

---

*Update:* It appears from an internal trace that in the integral

```
Integrate[Integrate[f[x] x^2, x] - Integrate[f[x], x] x^2, x]
```

the constant `x^2` multiplying the second integral of the integrand is replaced with a placeholder via a rule `` x^2 -> Integrate`Y ``. But that also replaces the `x^2` in the first integral, which indeed would result in `0`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Indeed, your workaround resolves the ambituities surrounding `x`. With some replacements afterwards, it may help to fix my original problem.
Your update pointed me to the TraceInternal option, and makes clear where the problem originates. I am not nearly sufficiently familiar with Mathematica's internal workings to understand why `x^2 -> Integrate\`Y` is done like this and what it implies. To me it continues to _feel_ like a bug, which I will need to work around. [Jens's reply here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16100/44584) is useful for that as well.

Comment: Indeed, while constructs like `Table` and `Plot` effectively use `Block` under the hood to localize variables, `Integrate` does *not*, which has always struck me as an oversight (but I imagine there must be some reason for that). As a consequence, things like `Plot[Integrate[x^2, {x, 0, 1}], {x, 0, 1}]` throw an error, because `x` isn't localized inside `Integrate` (not that I would recommend this code to begin with).

Comment: @march `Block[]` wouldn't help here, since `x` is never given a value by `Integrate[]` and the replacement would still mess things up. Rather, the `x`'s need to be localized, but I'm not sure how to do that in a good way transparent to the user.